# Get list of shared Dropbox folders with Java API

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I am writing Dropbox console application in Java. Is there any way to get list and quantity of shared folders for my Dropbox account?

Comment: have a look at: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't understand what I should to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [official Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java), you can use the [`DbxUserSharingRequests`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html) [`listFolders`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFolders--) and [`listFoldersContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFoldersContinue-java.lang.String-) methods to get the full list of shared folders in the connected user's account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have some example of code to do this task?

Comment: I don't have any sample code handy for that in particular unfortunately. Try it out, and if you run in to any issues, post a new question with the details.